# How to build Array of strings in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

How do I build an array of following type in C?

```
arr = [['S', 'NP+NP', 'S'],['S', 'NP+NUMBER', 'VP+VERB'],['S', 'VERB', 'NP']]
```

Answer (score 3):

```
char const* arr[][3] = {{"S", "NP+NP", "S"}, {"S", "NP+NUMBER", "VP+VERB"}, {"S", "VERB", "NP"}};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 const   char *strs[] = {"foo", "bar", "bletch", ...};
```

and you can access them like this

```
  for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_STRINGS; i++) {
        printf("%d: %s\n", i, strs[i]);
    }
```

Comment: it should be `const char *` or you'll probably have problem when editting it

Comment: why this should be constant ? this works fine. the NUMBER_OF_STRINGS should be constance when declaring.

Comment: Because "foo", et'al are read-only literals. and `NUMBER_OF_STRINGS` is actually optional in this case.